# How to get closest match of keyword search ransack rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, ransack

I am trying to get a closest match of a ransack keyword search in my rails app. In my search controller, i have

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    q = params[:q]
    @courses = current_academy.courses.search(title_cont: q).result
    @teachers = current_academy.teachers.search(firstname_cont: q).result
    @articles = current_academy.articles.current_locale.search(title_cont: q).result
  end
end
```

In my view, i have

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="{{ request.url_helpers.search_path }}">
  <label for="q">Search for:</label>
  <input id="mySearch" name="q" type="text" value="" />
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

At the moment, assuming the title of a course is "Digital Course", a search query for "digital" finds the course. The problem is a search query like "digital zzz" would return nothing and hence not find the course.

How do I make sure that search queries would return records with closest possible match using ransack. I have tried out other ransack predicates but cant get it to work. I would like to know the best way to do it.

Comment: I think you are looking for `matches_any` instead of  `cont` and then split the string on spaces. [Ransack Matchers](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers) however if you are looking for some form of scoring mechanism to determine best match then you are going to have to move on to something like `elasticsearch` or `thinking-sphinx`

Comment: the split method works, thanks